Selling One's Soul to the Devil
Following on from Q: When to use "x-is-the-same-as-y" or "x-is-like-y"?, how is "selling one's soul to the Devil" to be expressed in Latin?
In CHAT, Joonas pointed out that there is no "devil" figure in Roman mythology/theology (Not even Pluto?). The individual deities practised good-or-bad deeds according to whim. Romans were therefore wary of provoking their wrath, hence the propitiatory sacrifices made to capricious gods.
The concept of "selling one's soul", in a Faustian pact, might have meant little to a Roman. The Romans did understand the influence of evil: "sub malis avibus"--"under bad birds (evil influence)".
With the partial translation from the earlier, linked Q:

"(cogito fingentia arma venenorum essent idem ac) me ponentem sub malis avibus," giving:


"(I think that developing chemical weapons would be tantamount to/the same as) putting myself under evil spirits,"

alternatively,

"...idem ac stimulantem iram deorum,"


"...tantamount to provoking the wrath of the gods,"

do these translations work?

You ask in passing whether Pluto could be seen as the devil. I don't think so. First of all, the Roman or Greek underworld is not very similar to the Christian hell. Parts of it are similar, but all people good and bad go down there. Second, I don't think Pluto is evil the way the Christian devil is. The Greeks and Romans personified many things as gods or deities, but I don't think they did so with "good" and "evil" like Christianity.
